# Is is possible to add additional payment methods in QuickBooks Pro 2015?

Tags: payment, quickbooks

I'm using QuickBooks Pro 2015.  When paying a bill there are only two options for payment Method: Check or Credit Card.  Is there a way to add additional payment methods?  For example, what if a bill is paid with a debit card or ACH transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using QuickBooks for a while now, I've come to the conclusion that the payment methods available in QuickBooks are not so much about the actual payment method used for the transaction but the type of account that is used source the funds.  That is to say, for transactions funded by a checking account (e.g. payment via check, debit card, ACH, EFT, etc.) use the QuickBooks option to **Write Checks** when recording the transaction.  The actual transaction type can be denoted in the check number field.